# How to only preload required type (woff vs woff2) depending on browser?

Tags: html, reactjs, preload

I am using the following [react-helmet](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-helmet) code and I see both `woff` and `woff2` files are preloaded by Firefox (which is inefficient given only `woff2` is required).

Is it normal Firefox loads both? How can I tell the browser to only preload required file?

```
<Helmet
  link={[
    {
      rel: "preload",
      href: "/static/media/open-sans-latin-400.347639ec.woff",
      as: "font",
      type: "font/woff",
      crossOrigin: "anonymous",
    },
    {
      rel: "preload",
      href: "/static/media/open-sans-latin-400.f57a62e9.woff2",
      as: "font",
      type: "font/woff2",
      crossOrigin: "anonymous",
    },
  ]}
/>
```

Comment: You find a solution with this?

Comment: Hey @jamesemanon, no... I ended up preloading only `woff2` fonts.

Comment: Preloading only the woff2 fonts is the right solution. Support for woff is only needed for IE11 and earlier, and those browsers will never be on a mobile device.